# How to design classes in right way (sending messages)

Tags: c++, design

Trying to design small project in right way and have a trouble in it:\

about task: need to realize multiplication of big numbers, using fft

First, i have classes

```
class LargeNumber{};
class Field{}; -- abstract (maybe interface would be better)
class C_C:public virtual Field{};
class Z_p:public virtual Field{};
```

So, LargeNumber can use Z_P(modulo P) or C_C(complex) classes (more correct: C_C and Z_P have Mul and Sum functions to multiply LargeNumber objects)

but another task more interesting and difficult.

I need to calculate all operations and time each 'big' operation take. And also need to throw messages and create logs.

How to solve this problem? ( what should i do? )

Also will be great, if you comment patterns and your best practices.
and so this classes:

```
class LargeNumber {
  private:
  int length;
  vector <short int> number;
  public:
  //prototype
  LargeNumber clone(){            
        return (*this);
  }
  //get
  int Length() const;
  vector <short int> Number()const;      
  //static
  static LargeNumber& GenerateOne(int);// create new LargeNumber
  static void Print(const LargeNumber& print);
  //constructors
  LargeNumber();
  LargeNumber(const LargeNumber& obj);
  explicit LargeNumber(int len);      
  explicit LargeNumber(vector <short int>);
  LargeNumber(int,int);
  //destructors
  ~LargeNumber();    
  void Kill();
  //operators
  LargeNumber& operator= (const LargeNumber& );
  LargeNumber& operator--();    
  LargeNumber& operator++();
  bool operator<(const LargeNumber&)const;


  };


 class Field {
  private:
  inline int max(const int a, const int b){return (a>b?a:b);}       
  inline int min(const int a, const int b){return (a<b?a:b);}     
  int i;
  //need Mod and 2**P-1
  LargeNumber& Deux (const int );

  LargeNumber& Mod (LargeNumber&);
  public:
         virtual ~Field();
         virtual LargeNumber& Sum (const LargeNumber& , const LargeNumber& );
         virtual LargeNumber& Sub (const LargeNumber& , const LargeNumber& );
         virtual LargeNumber& Mul (const LargeNumber& , const LargeNumber& );        
         virtual LargeNumber& Pow (const LargeNumber& , const LargeNumber& );
         virtual bool Prime (LargeNumber& );


  };
```

Comment: My first reaction: **don't use abbreviated and cryptic names** such as `C_C` and `Z_p`, nor method names like `Mul` and `Sum`. Code is written once, read many times. Even with experimental or throwaway code, it is best to get into the habit of using meaningful, easy to read names *always*. Your future teammates - and the future you - will be glad you did.

Comment: @PéterTörök have a look at the mathematical term 'Field', which is (loosely speaking) a Group on which both addition and multiplication and their inverses (subtraction, division) are defined. E.g Q (ratios), R (real numbers), and C (complex numbers) are fields with infinite number of elements, though the integers are not. The only fields with a finite number of elements, are based on the integers (Z) modulo a prime p (and multi-dimensional vectors of the same Z_p). Therefor `Z_p` and `C_C` are perfectly understandable in this domain, and are not cryptic.

Comment: ok, thank you! will rewrite code!

fft - fast fourier transformation. 
Multiplication of Big numbers can be done with using fft (Schönhage–Strassen algorithm)
and more about fft: this operation is determine on group (and also on field and ring too).
so, really `Field` must be named like `FftCore` or something similar. 
and `C_C` - `ComplexField` and `Z_P` `Modulo_Prime_P` or something similar.

Comment: but about another task:
i need to gather statistics about time it executes and about count of operations it takes. 
also i need to make logs of everyting.

for this i suppose about classes `Statistics`, `TimeKeeper` ( maybe a part of `Statistics`) and `LogFormer`

But can't understand HOW _they_ must interact with previous classes.

Comment: @Sjoerd, thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware of these terms (IIRC the Hungarian terminology we studied at uni was different). I removed my comment.

Comment: @PéterTörök Glad to help :) I'll leave my comment as help for future readers facing the same problem.

Comment: okey, but how about gathering statistics? 
is this a good way to make abstract class, which can throw messages? 
and how it must interact with other classes? 
(agregation or compostion or inheritance)? 
please, comment these questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a good existing implementation of arbitrary-precision arithmetic, like Bruno Haible's CLN (which is partly based on GNU GMP).

Comment: Wow, I should +1 you solely for understanding the question! :)

Comment: I guess the OP's task is to implement this by hand.

Comment: i need to check number for it prime-property, both two numbers and then must calculate it ( multiplication ) 
about realization - any working under Windows-Os ( also GUI - Qt the best way )

Comment: If you're dealing with whole numbers, GMP will do it.   It also includes an example primality tester.   There are faster algorithms, but it's at least reasonably simple (I think it's Pollard's rho method).